# Creating a drop down menu and showing the sub menu underneath the main menu

Tags: css, html

I tried to create a drop down menu but instead of the drop down menu being under one of the main menu buttons and invisible unless hovered over it appears on the side and is visible. What did I miss?

```
<body>
<div class="nav-bar">
        <nav class="box-nav-bar">
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="/Home">HOME</a></li>
                <li> <a href="/Home">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li> <a href="/Home">SERVICES</a>
                    <ul class="drop_down">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Dolor sit amet  </a>                      
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Conse ctetur </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Latest</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Archive</a>
                                    </li>                      
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="/Home">PROJECTS</a></li>
                <li> <a href="/Home">CONTACTS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
  </body>
```

CSS code:

```
.box-nav-bar ul{
    display:inline-block;

    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 20px;


}
.box-nav-bar ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;

    text-align: center;

}
.box-nav-bar ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.box-nav-bar ul li:hover{
    background-color: grey;

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

found it. I needed to display:none in the drop_down class.